# Facing error awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=rawdata.2018-01-14.csv FNR=1069) fatal: cannot open pipe `date -d (Too many open files)

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix, awk

I am facing an error as below when I am trying to concatenate too many csv files together.

Facing error

> ```
>   awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=rawdata.2018-01-14.csv.bkp FNR=1069) fatal: cannot open pipe `date "+%F %T" -d "Jan 13 22:00:12 2018"1' (Too many open files)
>   awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=rawdata.2018-01-15.csv.bkp FNR=1070) fatal: cannot open pipe `date "+%F %T" -d "Jan 13 22:00:12 2018"1' (Too many open files)
> ```

etc... till FNR=1074

Out of 60 files its processing first 44 files and next 16 files are giving error while they are concatenated.

Code :

```
for i in rawdata.*.csv;  
do  
echo $i;  
awk '{if($0) printf("%s\t%s\n", FILENAME, $0); else print FILENAME;}' $i > $i.bk;  
sed -e "1,2d" $i.bk > $i.bkp  
awk -e '{tempdate="date \"+%F %T\" -d \""$6" "$7" "$8" "$9"\"" tempdate | getline tmpdate; print tmpdate "\t" "source-" $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $3 "\t" $4 "\t" $9 "\t" $10 "\t" $11 ; close(tempdate) }' $i.bkp | sed 's/.//5' >  $i.bakp
done  
cat rawdata.*.bakp > rawdatacombnew.csv  
rm rawdata.*.bk  
rm rawdata.*.bkp  
rm rawdata.*.bakp
```

any suggestions would be very helpful.

one observation I saw is that , the file size for increased from processing the 45th file in my example. Is size an issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Add your awk code to your question.

Comment: please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Do a `ulimit -n` and if necessary increase it.

Comment: Hi all, I had added my code.Please suggest !!

Comment: @cdarke , I had checked the ulimit -n and it is showing as 1024.I am not sure how it is impacting my code ? OR do I need to change it ?

Comment: Its as if the files descriptors are not being closed after each `awk` and `sed`, but that would not make sense (sorry, thinking out loud).  There is some more diagnostics you can do if you are on Linux.  That is, take a look at /proc for the `awk` process and look in the fd subdirectory for that pid.

Comment: Hi all , thank you for replying to my post . This helped me to dig and learn a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a semicolon between `tempdate="..."` and `tempdate | getline` so you're continually appending to tempdate and idk what exactly is being piped to getline!

There's no benefit to cramming your scripts onto single lines, just write it naturally and it'll be much easier to read and spot issue in:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '{
    tempdate="date \"+%F %T\" -d \""$6" "$7" "$8" "$9"\""
    if ( (tempdate | getline tmpdate) > 0 ) {
        print tmpdate, "source-" $1, $2, $3, $4, $9, $10, $11
    }
    close(tempdate)
}' "$i.bkp"
```

I tidied up a couple of other things while I was at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Ed Morton !!   I modified the code with the modifications as suggested by you above. It worked ! Could you please help me understand why we need to check this condition (tempdate | getline tmpdate) > 0 and how is it impacting with my code ?

Comment: You're welcome. Because getline can always silently fail and then youd be corrupting your output by using the value of tmpdate from the last time it succeeded without ever knowing. You should probably add an "else" to print a warning too. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for the many caveats related to using getline.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful information and suggestion !